# Retriving data from req.files in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, multer

I'm using multer to uploading images. How to get specific file from `req.files`? When I was trying to got it by index it failed. I can't get it also by fieldname so how can I get it? When I'm logging it I see that it's normal array so I think it's problem related to Typescript (which I'm using). Can someone help me with that?

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import multer from "multer";
import AuthenticationRequest from "../interfaces/AuthenticationRequest";
import ResponseError from "../interfaces/ResponseError";
import Product from "../models/Product";
const createProduct = async (
    req: AuthenticationRequest,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction
) => {
    if (req.files) {
        const paths = [];
        console.log(req.files);
    } else {
        const err: ResponseError = new Error("Files are required");
        err.status = 422;
        throw err;
    }
};
const productController = { createProduct };
export default productController;
```

Comment: can please show what is the result of this statement console.log(req.files)?

Comment: `[
  {
    fieldname: 'images',
    originalname: 'xbox.png',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    destination: 'public/images',
    filename: '1670513500113-xbox.png',
    path: 'public\\images\\1670513500113-xbox.png',
    size: 33377
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'images',
    originalname: 'School Season Background.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: 'public/images',
    filename: '1670513500114-School Season Background.jpg',
    path: 'public\\images\\1670513500114-School Season Background.jpg',
    size: 26068
  }
]`

Comment: where is the place you try to retrieve the file?

Comment: You are using it correctly.

Comment: In this code snippet I don't retrive it because when I'm trying to do some array operations on req.file I'm getting `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"asd"' can't be used to index type '{ [fieldname: string]: File[]; } | File[]'.`

Comment: How do you use multer? Are you using Multer as middleware and do you attach file to req object?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can handle the file upload,for more info visit [this](https://attacomsian.com/blog/uploading-files-nodejs-express).
Here the photos is the fieldname name.

```
  if (!req.files) {
  res.send({
     status: false,
     message: "No file uploaded",
  });
  } else {
  let data = {};

  //loop all files
  let photo = req.files.photos;

  //move photo to uploads directory
  photo.mv("./uploads/" + photo.name);

  //push file details
  data = {
     name: photo.name,
     mimetype: photo.mimetype,
     size: photo.size,
  };

  //return response
  res.send({
     status: true,
     message: "Files are uploaded",
     data: data,
  });
  }
```

Comment: When I'm trying to do anyone operations on req.files I'm getting this error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"asd"' can't be used to index type '{ [fieldname: string]: File[]; } | File[]'.`

Comment: Please go through my code i have made it for single file only.